# How to set focus on anchor tag's text exculding css background image?

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have used following CSS to set focus on anchor tag:

```
a:focus
{
outline: 1px dotted black;
}
```

As I have used background image in css to show pdf icon(pdf-icon.png) before download link of pdf file. As tab focus occurs it select text of anchor tag with pdf-icon.png image. 
And My CSS to show pdf icon image is like this:

```
a.pdf-link
{
line-height: 30px;
background: url(../Images/pdf-icon.png) no repeat;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 4px 0px 4px 26px;
}
```

But I want to set focus only on Anchor tag's text i.e. 'DownLoad PDF', do not want focus on 'pdf-icon.png' image .

My code on .aspx page is like this:

```
<div>
<a class="pdf-link" href="http://example.com/a.pdf" target=" _blank" shape=""> Download PDF </a>
</div>
```

Can anyone assist me to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you really need two anchor tags? You could put the icon inside the first one and your problem is solved.

Comment: @ DiogoDoreto First of all thank you for your fastest reply :) . But my code on .aspx code is like this: <div>
<a class="pdf-link" href="http://example.com/a.pdf" target=" _blank" shape=""> Download PDF </a>
</div>  Will your solution work for that code??

Answer (score 0):

Use a more expressive selector, such as:

```
.pdf-link:focus
{
outline: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/4932817/ramon-sena Thank you for your reply.  But I have used other simple Anchor tag in my .aspx page. I want to set focus on those elements also. So your solution is not working according to my requirement.